# Problem with SWFObject in IE

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I'm having a problem with SWFObject in IE.

The swf-file shows, but everything below the swf doesn't.

Here's the URL: http://timkjaerlange.com/wip/co2penhagen/

Any ideas to what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `</object>` tags.